# Unable to share files between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cifs

I just installed the Ubuntu app from Windows store on my Windows 10 machine. Ran successfully through all the installs, updates etc., configured the shared folder in Windows. The `sudo mount.cifs` command gives me the following error:

```
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system

mount error(19): No such device

Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I was unable to find a solution using Google. Please advise what to check...

This is the exact command I ran:

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=XXXX //XXX.XXX.X.XX/Linux_files /home/XXXX/WindowsShare
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run this command it has the format

`sudo -S mount -t cifs [share] [mountpoint] -o [options]`

I haven't seen that mount.cifs kind of command, nor the share and mountpoint after the `-o`.

Not an expert, so it may not be the syntax that is getting you.

I also use a "real" system so the WSL may be different.

Comment: I tried your syntax -- it was exactly the same result (same error)...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use WSL 2 on Windows. For more information, see e.g. here: https://superuser.com/a/1757154/326923